# How to properly dynamically include jQuery and jQueryUI on many pages

Tags: jquery, widget, installation

I'm building a widget that can be included on many different websites.  This widget will require the use of jQuery.  My customers will install my widget via a  tag that will be included before their `</body>` tags (just like how Google Analytics works)

I'm at a bit of a loss on how to deal with the problem of everyone's website environments being different.

Currently my solution is to just dynamically load load both jQuery and jQueryUI in my JS code which they will include just before their `</body>` tag.  However, this causes issues if they already have jQuery loaded on their website.

One solution I searched for it to detect if they already have jQuery included via:

```
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') { 
  // include jQuery 
}
if (typeof jQuery.ui == 'undefined')
{
  // include jQueryUI
}
```

However, this caused problems when they already had jQuery loaded... It seems like if they already have jQuery included on their website, my JS widget is not able to access the jQuery library that's already loaded from the customer's website, as I get an error saying that it doesn't recognize the '$'.

I'm sure this problem has been solved before, but I can't seem to find the answer.

## UPDATE

To clarify things a bit... the code I have included above is okay, it doesn't cause issues.  Here are the use cases:

### Use Case 1

1. User doesn't have jQuery on their site
2. My JS script dynamically loads jQuery and waits for the script to
   finish loading
3. All is well

### Use Case 2

1. User does have jQuery on their site and doesn't have jQueryUI
2. My JS script dynamically loads jQueryUI only and waits for the
   script to finish loading
3. My JS file tries to invoke $.ajax and it fails :(

### Use Case 3

1. User does have jQuery on their site and does have jQueryUI
2. My JS script doesn't need to load anything so it doesn't
3. My JS file tries to invoke $.ajax and it fails :(

#### So the question is...

Why is it that my JS file can **only** access $.ajax (and other jQuery functions) when it loads jQuery itself?

Comment: What do you use jQuery for? maybe it would be better to instead adapt your code to not rely on jQuery rather than including xkb of additional code that you don't really need.

Comment: I agree with @KevinB. If jQuery and jQuery UI are hard dependencies of your widget, then you need to communicate this to your users, otherwise you need to work without it. Your widget is *very* different from Google Analytics in this aspect. This is not an unreasonable request (think of any jQuery plugin).

Comment: I second the notion that at the very least, your widget should not depend on jQuery UI.  If you can't live without it, make sure you define a css scope for jQuery UI to avoid conflicts.  If they don't have jQuery, you may want to define a namespace to avoid conflicts with other libraries.  I'd personally indicate that jQuery is a dependency and use something other than jQuery UI.

Comment: I make heavy use of jQuery throughout the widget... but I believe I only use on jQueryUI function (draggable), so it's reasonable to drop that dependency.  However, this still doesn't address the issue I'm having...  even if I don't worry about loading jQueryUI, my widget still has issues accessing jQuery if I don't forcefully load it in my JS widget.  This is the error I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'ajax' of undefined`

Comment: How do you know that the host page's version of jQuery is compatible with your code? At the very least you need to check the jQuery version as well as the mere presence if jQuery, and test your code with all the versions you support. Then if an incompatible jQuery is found, load your own and use `jQuery.noConflict()` to give it a private name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so as it turns out the code and everything I had was working fine... it's just that some of the websites I was installing my widget on must have been using the $ "namespace" for something other than jQuery.

So I had to go through my client JS file and replace all occurrences of '$' with 'jQuery'.

**Examples**

changed: `$.ajax({});`
to: `jQuery.ajax({});`

changed: `$("#textbox").change(function () {});`
to: `jQuery("#textbox").change(function () {});`

Answer (score 0):

try using this instead:

```
if(typeof(jQuery) === undefined){
    //load jquery
}
else{
    //jquery already there

    if(typeof(jQuery.ui) === undefined){
        //load jquery ui
    }
}
```

UPDATED

Comment: there is no need to check for jquery.ui, unless jquery is included

Comment: I see what you're getting at, but how will this address the issue of jQuery not being accessible if my JS widget doesn't load jQuery itself (as it's seems to have issues accessing the jQuery function if I don't forcefully load jQuery myself)